# Error parameter not taking values when calling functions

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def crawler(seed,maxcount,publicationDetails):
  Q=[seed]
  count=0
  while(Q!=[] and count<maxcount):
    count+=1
    url=Q.pop(0)
    print(url)
    code=requests.get(url)
    plain=code.text
    s=BeautifulSoup(plain,"html.parser")
    for link in s.findAll("a"):
      newurl=link.get("href")
      if(newurl!=None and newurl!="/"):
        newurl=newurl.strip()
        if(newurl[0:5]!="http://" and newurl[0:6]!="http://"):
          if(url[len(url) -1] == '/'):
            newurl=url + newurl
          else:
            newurl=url + "/"+ newurl
        Q.append(newurl)

  publicationDetails=[]
  for page in range(0,1):
     
     page1=requests.get(newurl)
     soup=BeautifulSoup(page1.text,"html.parser")
     publications=soup.find_all("h3",{"class":"title"})
     for this_publications in publications:
            if(this_publications.find("a")):
                publicationDetails+=[{"name":this_publications.string,
                              "link":this_publications.find("a")["href"]
                              }]
crawler("https://pureportal.coventry.ac.uk/en/organisations/school-of-economics-finance-and-accounting/persons/",12,publicationDetails[5]["link"])
```

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-924a9dc1f5b3> in <module>()
----> 1 crawler("https://pureportal.coventry.ac.uk/en/organisations/school-of-economics-finance-and-accounting/persons/",12,publicationDetails[5]["link"])

NameError: name 'publicationDetails' is not defined
```

Comment: `publicationDetails` is a local variable inside the function. You can't use it as an argument when calling the function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Barmar can you help me with the correcting this code

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. What is `publicationDetails[5]["link"]` supposed to be before the function has even been called?

Comment: Why does the function receive that as a parameter in the first place? It assigns `publicationDetails=[]` so it never uses the parameter value.